# Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, windows, reactjs, dom, webpack-dev-server

I created a Reactjs component running in webpack and looks like this:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
    render() {
        //debugger
        console.log('hi there')
        return <div>
            <h1>hello world</h1>
        </div>;
    }
}

/*
 * 
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Part of my index.html looks like this:

```
<body>

<div id="root">
</div>

</body>
```

I am getting the error see above when goin to http://localhost:9999/bundletje#/. How can I fix this?

Comment: where are you including your javascript? In the head tag, after the body, or what?

Comment: There is no script tag in the index.html. I am running webpack-dev-server.

Comment: u r running webpack dev server but what it does is provide a server on a specific port, nothing else, you have to include the bundle create by webpack, this bundle will be the one which contains all your react code, include this line it will work: <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script> in body.

Comment: you do understand that localhost is local... it can be used in that form - from your pc only!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your are trying to use `root` element before it is being created in the first place. Maybe you should try:

```
<body>

<div id="root">
</div>

</body>
<script>
  class Application extends React.Component {
    render() {
        //debugger
        console.log('hi there')
        return <div>
            <h1>hello world</h1>
        </div>;
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: Ok cool. I have a question: how do I run a production version of this app in windows? I dont need webpack-dev-server right?

Comment: that is a kind of a different answer..in short: start digging about [ReactNative](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/). in addition: if by **cool** you mean that my solution works, then - you're welcome :)